# Tippecanoe unable to open database file

Tags: geojson, ubuntu, windows, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am trying to use tippecanoe to convert my GeoJSON into mbtiles like so

`tippecanoe -o c:/users/path/to/newfile.mbtiles -Z 0 -z 8 c:/users/path/to/file.geojson`

However, I keep getting the error `tippecanoe: c:/users/path/to/newfile.mbtiles: unable to open database file`

For reference, I am using Windows so I have had to download Ubuntu in order to be able to use Tippecanoe. I've successfully installed it and its dependencies as per instructions.

Answer (score 1):

1. run your Ubuntu as administrator
2. the syntax of windows vs unix path is different, read more about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337443/what-is-a-full-path-name) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/)